# MS Dynamics AX 2009 SSRS pass parameter to subreport

Tags: dynamics-ax-2009

Is there a fix for subreport? I can't view content in local development. Please help

Answer (score 0):

If the feature you are asking about is Drill Through Actions, I would recommend wathcing this very good public screencast done by Saveen Reddy: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G_uTQ5_EVhM

I hope this helps!